# Why my Decision Tree Model is not further bifurcated in to Age

Tags: predictive-modeling, decision-trees, beginner

I've created a Decision Tree Model for expected candidates that buyed Villa.

Though the Drilling down Green highlighted box, show data has Age in it.

**Question**- But why my model is not bifurcating it further into Age?

**Deposit & Age** both are having **content type** as **Discretized** as **DicretizationBucketCount** as **5 & 10 respectively**.

[Source Data Link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtFu80OEpmZKgRRXvMdn4L79AXHU)

[image: Model Data Viewer]

Comment: Welcome to Data Science SE. Without the data or more information about the distribution of each individual variable and how they are distributed among you tree nodes it will be hard to help you.

Comment: @Stereo just added source data link, while creating model , attribute name "Villa Buyer" is "predictOnly", where as "Age" and "Deposit" are choosen as input to model, content type and bucket size mentioned in question. If there anything else you required please let me know

Answer (score 2):

You have your Decision Tree set to a default expansion of 3 levels. The Decison Tree works with the most significant features first, and it has not deemed age as important. Increase the default expansion to more levels to see the bifurcation of age.

A word of caution: deep decision trees are prone to overfitting.

Comment: i tried "All levels" for Default Expansion but still same issue